# Regex for greping emails in file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I would like to validate emails from text files in a directory using `bash`.

My regex:

```
grep -Eoh \
         "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,8}\b" * \
         | sort -u > mail_list
```

This regex satisfies all my requirements but it cannot exclude addresses such:

```
^%&blah@gmail.com
```

and

```
with.dot@sale..department.company-name.com
```

(with 2 and more dots).

These kinds of addresses should be excluded.

How can I modify this regex to exclude these types of emails?
I can use only one expression for this task.

Comment: A good regex to check emails: http://stackoverflow.com/a/719543/1983854

Comment: Or, more modern (in terms of both regex features and address specification): http://stackoverflow.com/a/1917982/1030675

Comment: As mentioned in the link above, regular expressions aren't really the way to go. I would suggest using something like [Email::Valid](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Valid-1.194/lib/Email/Valid.pm) in Perl, or [`filter_var`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
'\b[A-Za-z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,8}\b'
```

I added an alphanumeric group to the front, to force emails to begin with at least one letter or number, after which they may also have symbols.

After the `@` sign, I added a group which can contain any number of letters or numbers, followed by **one** period. However, this group can be repeated multiple times, thus being able to match `long.domain.name.com`.

Finally, the regex ends with the final string as you had it, for example `'com'`.

---

#### Update:

Since `\b` matches a word boundary, and the symbols `^%&` are not considered part of the word 'blah', the above will still match `blah@gmail.com` even though it is preceded by undesired characters. To avoid this, use a [Negative Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind). This will require using `grep -P` instead of `-E`:

```
grep -P '(?<![%&^])\b[A-Za-z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,8}\b'
```

The `(?<![%&^])` tells regex to match further only if the string is not preceded by the characters `%&^`.

Comment: Thank you! But I still can not exclude addresses such ^%&blah@gmail.com. Now in my output file I have blah@gmail.com. But my goal is to completely exclude such addresses from mail_list. For my purposes both ^%&blah@gmail.com and blah@gmail.com are not valid addresses.

Comment: The problem is that `\b` matches the edge of a word, and those symbols are not considered part of the word 'blah'. You could try to put a space or `\s` instead of the `\b`, which would match email addresses that come after a white-space.

Comment: You can also try a [Negative Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) with `grep -P (?<![%&^])\b[A-Za-z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,8}\b'`. The `(?<![%&^])` tells regex to match further only if the string is not preceded by the characters `%&^`.

Comment: I tried this (\s), but it excludes all normal addreses I have. I use bash in debian, but my colleague uses ubuntu and uses \s (as you advise) and has satisfactory result. May be problem is in shell differences...

Comment: I'm using GNU `grep` v. 2.18, on `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

The email address `^%&blah@gmail.com` is actually [a valid email address](http://sphinx.mythic-beasts.com/~pdw/cgi-bin/emailvalidate).

You can do this in Perl using the [`Email::Valid` module](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Valid-1.194/lib/Email/Valid.pm) (this assumes that each entry is on a new line):

```
perl -MEmail::Valid -ne 'print if Email::Valid->address($_)' file1 file2
```

#### file1

```
not email
abc@test.com
```

#### file2

```
not email
def@test.com
^%&blah@gmail.com
with.dot@sale..department.company-name.com
```

#### output

```
abc@test.com
def@test.com
^%&blah@gmail.com
```